# Is it possible to configure CLion to compile source files in a project independently?

Tags: c, compilation, ide, clion

I am currently doing some Project Euler challenges in C using the JetBrains CLion IDE. When I completed these in Python and Java (in PyCharm and IntelliJ, respectively), I was always able to create a single project named "ProjectEuler" and add any number of source files that I could execute independently. However, it seems the same isn't possible in CLion. Each of the source files I use to solve a problem contains a main() function, and CMake is unhappy about that everytime I attempt to compile ("multiple definition of 'main'").

Is there a way to configure CLion to only compile and execute a single source file in a project at a time without having to rewrite my CMakeLists.txt or create a new project for every problem everytime?

I'm aware that C is compiled and not interpreted like Java or Python, but I could conceivably just compile every single source file manually. Is there a way to configure CLion to do the same? If so, how?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You could define multiple executables in the CMakeLists.txt for each problem.

instead of

```
add_executable(projecteuler ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

you could define

```
add_executable(problem1 problem1.c)
add_executable(problem2 problem2.c)
```

Then you get for each executable (problem1, problem2 etc.) a run configuration, which you can run independently. In this case you won't have to rewrite every time, instead you just add the new source file to a new executable.

Comment: There isn't a way to make CLion add the source automatically? I know it's not much to add it but it's could be better

Comment: If you add a new C++ source or header file you can check "Add to targets" and then select the targets/executables where you want to add the file in the CMakeLists.txt. But the target has to be already in the CMakeLists.txt file.

Comment: @InvisibleUn1corn I agree that it's nice if we can add `add_executable` more easily. For this purpose, I made a plugin for CLion "[C/C++ Single File Execution Plugin](http://corochann.com/projects/single-file-execution-plugin)".

Answer (score 8):

Even I was facing the same problem, it's a tiring job to edit CMake file and add executable every time. So I found a solution to this,

There is a plugin which does it seamlessly for you.

Just add this [plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/8352-c-c--single-file-execution) to your CLion and whichever file you want to make is executable right click and add it as Executable,

It will automatically edit your CMake file.

Link:

https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/8352-c-c--single-file-execution

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.4)

add_subdirectory(src/prj1)
add_subdirectory(src/prj2)
```

then in each directory create an other CMakeLists.txt like this one :

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.4)
project(prj1)

set(EXEC_NAME prj1)

set(SOURCE_FILES
    main_prj1.cpp
    x.cpp
    y.cpp
)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")

set(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH ../../dist/${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE})

add_executable(${EXEC_NAME} ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

You can use `file(GLOB SOURCE_FILES *.cpp)` if you want to automatically add files in your compilation. But keep in mind that this "trick" is strongly not encouraged.

This will also automatically add build configurations to CLion.

Answer (score 2):

You can add these lines to your CMakeLists.txt .

```
    #GLOB_RECURSE will find files in all subdirectories that match the globbing expressions and store it into the variable.
    file(GLOB_RECURSE APP_SOURCES *.c)
    foreach (testsourcefile ${APP_SOURCES})
        #get filename without extension
        get_filename_component(testname ${testsourcefile} NAME_WE)
        #add executable for all file
        add_executable(${testname} ${testsourcefile})
    endforeach (testsourcefile ${APP_SOURCES})
```

You will have to reload cmake project (Tools -> Cmake) every time you add or delete files from your project. Also build time will increase if you add more number of files. Alternative you can create more directories and subdirectories and use `file(GLOB_RECURSE APP_SOURCES path/to/*.c)` so it will build only those files.

Answer (score 0):

After adding executables in CMakeLists.txt for each source file one must reload the file by pressing `Reload` button on upper right corner and then set `run debug configuration` to that source file name which he wants to run.