# Clion, making new file in project in c++

Tags: c++, clion

I'm trying to learn how to code in c++. I can't find anywhere how to simply create a new file in Clion in a project that will work when I run it. The first file created in a new project runs fine. Do I have to edit the cmakelists.txt file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From https://stackoverflow.com/a/32177224/6614294:

Modify `CMakeLists.txt` like this (example):

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.3)
project(test_build)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")

set(BUILD_1 main)
set(SOURCE_FILES_1 main.cc) //where main.cc is your first main/program
add_executable(${BUILD_1} ${SOURCE_FILES_1})

set(BUILD_2 main_2)
set(SOURCE_FILES_2 main_2.cc) //where main_2.cc is your second main/program
add_executable(${BUILD_2} ${SOURCE_FILES_2})
```

Answer (score 4):

You can make it from mouse context menu over the folder where you like to have  new file [image: new file creation].